# How to calculate distance in "km" using a points geometry column to the nearest linestring geometry column in SQL Server spatial

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I am looking to create a field that tells me the nearest neighbour distance in km between 2 geometric columns.

I have a point dataset and multiline dataset both with the geometric fields.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    p.GEOM.STDistance(l.GEOM) AS distance
FROM 
    [points] p, [dbo].[lines] l
```

after running this query I get the following message

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
>   System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
>   System.ArgumentException:

Could you help me with this one please?

Much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: STDistance specifically works with geography types. You may have a mix of types in your geometry columns, e.g.: Points, Polygons and LineStrings.

Comment: Correct, so I can't do points on lines?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate you have bad spatial data in one of the tables but the query you're using has issues as well.  Run this

```
select ID, geom.STisValid() from lines
and 
SELECT ID, geom.STisValid() from points
```

To see if you have any bad geometry records.   If you do run

```
update table 'with bad spatial datatype'
set geom = geom.MakeValid()
```

Once you're sure the spatial data is valid rework your query to use a cross join (compare every line to every point (and get the distance) and store the results in a temp table.
Query the temp table for the min(distance) for each point or line.  Provided you only need to know the closest feature and not a distance you can do all this with geometry data. If you need to have a measure in feet or meters you will need to convert your data from geometry to geography.

If you have a large number of features in either table the cross join could take forever.  Try to work it out on a subset.